# How to set max-length for an input in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap for my form and show errors if validation failed. Below is a piece of code. I want to set the user name min and max length to 6 and 16 respectively. If the input value doesn't meet the validation, an error message `Minimum of 6 / Maximum of 16 characters` should be shown. But it works fine for inputing less than 6 characters but doesn't work for the value more than 16 characters. It looks like the `data-maxlength` has no impact on the form validation. What's wrong with my code?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="user-username-input">User Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-username-input" placeholder="User Name" data-maxlength="16" data-minlength="6" data-error="Minimum of 6 / Maximum of 16 characters" required>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
minlength="number"  
maxlength="number"
```

(Change number to the number needed.)

You can use for the lengths.